# Comparing Similar Data Frames with Like-Columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'd like to compare the difference in data frames.  `xyz` has all of the same columns as `abc`, but it has an additional column.

In the comparison, I'd like match up the two like columns (`Sport`) but only show the `SportLeague` in the output (if a difference exists, that is).  Example, instead of showing 'Soccer' as a difference, show 'Soccer:MLS', which is the adjacent column in `xyz`)

Here's a screenshot of the two data frames:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

abc = {'Sport' : ['Football', 'Basketball', 'Baseball', 'Hockey'], 'Year' : ['2021','2021','2022','2022'], 'ID' : ['1','2','3','4']}
abc = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in abc.items()})
abc
xyz = {'Sport' : ['Football', 'Football', 'Basketball', 'Baseball', 'Hockey', 'Soccer'], 'SportLeague' : ['Football:NFL', 'Football:XFL', 'Basketball:NBA', 'Baseball:MLB', 'Hockey:NHL', 'Soccer:MLS'], 'Year' : ['2022','2019', '2022','2022','2022', '2022'], 'ID' : ['2','0', '3','2','4', '1']}
xyz = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in xyz.items()})
xyz = xyz.sort_values(by = ['ID'], ascending = True)
xyz
```

Code already tried:

```
abc.compare(xyz, align_axis=1, keep_shape=False, keep_equal=False)
```

The error I get is the following (since the data frames don't have the exact same columns):
[image]

Example.  If xyz['Sport'] does not show up anywhere within abc['Sport'], then show xyz['SportLeague]' as the difference between the data frames

Further clarification of the logic:

Does abc['Sport'] appear anywhere in xyz['Sport']?  If not, indicate "Not Found in `xyz data frame`".  If it does exist, are its corresponding abc['Year'] and abc['ID'] values the same?  If not, show "Change from xyz['Year'] and xyz['ID'] to abc['Year'] and abc['ID'].

Does xyz['Sport'] appear anywhere in abc['Sport']?  If not, indicate "Remove `xyz['SportLeague']`".

What I've explained above is similar to the `.compare` method.  However, the data frames in this example may not be the same length and have different amounts of variables.

Comment: Please include the expected outcome (as a df) for the given example. Also, please edit your question some more: get rid of the images and simply include the actual dfs (abc, xyz) inside the question body (within triple backtick blocks) and reduce the error image to something like: "This attempt gives me the following error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`". Incidentially, `df.compare()` fails not just because you have different columns (could be easily fixed), but also because your dfs do not have the same length of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, we basically want to merge both DataFrames, and then apply a number of comparisons between both DataFrames, and add a column that explains the course of action to be taken, given a certain result of a given comparison.

Note: in the example here I have added one sport ('Cricket') to your df `abc`, to trigger the condition `abc['Sport']` does not exist in `xyz['Sport']`.

```
abc = {'Sport' : ['Football', 'Basketball', 'Baseball', 'Hockey','Cricket'], 'Year' : ['2021','2021','2022','2022','2022'], 'ID' : ['1','2','3','4','5']}
abc = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in abc.items()})
print(abc)

        Sport  Year ID
0    Football  2021  1
1  Basketball  2021  2
2    Baseball  2022  3
3      Hockey  2022  4
4     Cricket  2022  5
```

I've left `xyz` unaltered. Now, let's merge these two dfs:

```
df = xyz.merge(abc, on='Sport', how='outer', suffixes=('_xyz','_abc'))
print(df)

        Sport     SportLeague Year_xyz ID_xyz Year_abc ID_abc
0    Football    Football:XFL     2019      0     2021      1
1    Football    Football:NFL     2022      2     2021      1
2      Soccer      Soccer:MLS     2022      1      NaN    NaN
3    Baseball    Baseball:MLB     2022      2     2022      3
4  Basketball  Basketball:NBA     2022      3     2021      2
5      Hockey      Hockey:NHL     2022      4     2022      4
6     Cricket             NaN      NaN    NaN     2022      5
```

Now, we have a df where we can evaluate your set of conditions using `np.select(conditions, choices, default)`. Like this:

```
conditions  = [ df.Year_abc.isnull(), 
               df.Year_xyz.isnull(), 
               (df.Year_xyz != df.Year_abc) & (df.ID_xyz != df.ID_abc),
               df.Year_xyz != df.Year_abc,
               df.ID_xyz != df.ID_abc
               ]

choices     = [ 'Sport not in abc', 
               'Sport not in xyz', 
               'Change year and ID to xyz', 
               'Change year to xyz',
               'Change ID to xyz']
    
df['action'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Result as below with a new column `action` with notes on which course of action to take.

```
        Sport     SportLeague Year_xyz ID_xyz Year_abc ID_abc  \
0    Football    Football:XFL     2019      0     2021      1   
1    Football    Football:NFL     2022      2     2021      1   
2      Soccer      Soccer:MLS     2022      1      NaN    NaN   
3    Baseball    Baseball:MLB     2022      2     2022      3   
4  Basketball  Basketball:NBA     2022      3     2021      2   
5      Hockey      Hockey:NHL     2022      4     2022      4   
6     Cricket             NaN      NaN    NaN     2022      5   

                      action  
0  Change year and ID to xyz  # match, but mismatch year and ID
1  Change year and ID to xyz  # match, but mismatch year and ID
2           Sport not in abc  # no match: Sport in xyz, but not in abc
3           Change ID to xyz  # match, but mismatch ID 
4  Change year and ID to xyz  # match, but mismatch year and ID 
5                        nan  # complete match: no action needed
6           Sport not in xyz  # no match: Sport in abc, but not in xyz
```

Let me know if this is a correct interpretation of what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: this may need to be a separate question, but how would I then color code this based on the choices?

Comment: No need, easy enough. Create a list with same length as `choices`, and populate it with the colors you want as match for the strings. E.g. `colors = ['#D2122E', 'khaki', 'darkkhaki', 'indianred', 'gold']`. You can do HEX code or 'name'. Then something like this: `s = df.style.apply(lambda x: [f"background-color:{colors[choices.index(x)]}" if x in choices else f"background-color:{None}" for x in df.action]
, subset=["action"])`. `None` here for the "nan" values, but you can enter a color there too, of course. Next line: `s` for the print. Here applied only to column 'action' (= subset).

Comment: @HelpMeCode: incidentally, if in the future you post questions here on SO, feel free to tag me in a comment underneath (using "@username"), and I'll see if I have time to help out. And if so, let's hope I know the answer as well ;)